# Is there a possibility to hook to TailwindCSS rebuilding?

Tags: tailwind-css

I don't see any mention in their docs, but maybe someone knows: is there a possibility to hook to Tailwind rebuilding process?

So that when the Tailwind `--watch` mode rebuilds output CSS in respond to a change in template or component, I could also trigger my custom event(s) at this moment.

---

Ok, I can watch for updating of the `output.css` and I've read about [Watchman from Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/watchman), but maybe there is something else?